# Cannot get the drop down option value but the others textbox can in Laravel

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, laravel-8

I cannot get the drop-down option value, but the other text boxes can. So, for example, I get the following error when I select food as an option.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
> 'parcelContentCategory' cannot be null

But when I select others and type in the textbox, it's able to capture the data in the textbox.

**Edit.blade**

```
<label>Parcel Content Category</label></br>
<select id="parcelContentCategory" name="parcelContentCategory"
        value="{{ $delivery_orders->parcelContentCategory }}"
        requried focus onchange='checkvalue(this.value)'>
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Document">Document</option>
    <option value="Box">Box</option>
    <option>Other...</option>
</select>
</br>
<input type="text" id="textCat" name="parcelContentCategory" style='display:none'/>
</br>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkvalue(val) {
        if (val === "Other...")
            document.getElementById('textCat').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('textCat').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $orderID)
{
    $delivery_orders = DeliveryOrder::find($orderID);
    $delivery_orders->senderID=$request->get('senderID');
    $delivery_orders->receiverID=$request->get('receiverID');
    $delivery_orders->totalWeight=$request->get('totalWeight');
    $delivery_orders->parcelContentCategory=$request->input('parcelContentCategory');
    $delivery_orders->scheduleID=$request->get('scheduleID');
    $delivery_orders->update();

    return redirect('order/')->with('flash_message', 'Order Updated!');  
}
```

Comment: As error says **Column 'parcelContentCategory' cannot be null**, and null means empty or 0

Comment: actually I want the value from the option to be insert into database. Either the value from the option or the value of the others option which is input manually

Comment: Your select box and input has same name `<select id="parcelContentCategory" name="parcelContentCategory"` -  `<input type="text" id="textCat"  name="parcelContentCategory" style='display:none' />"` . and input doesnt have a `value=""`

Comment: Actually want should i put at my controller when I want the value whether it is from the others input or the option value into the database?